# Why do single quotes not behave identically in bash --posix and dash?

Tags: bash, shell, posix

Aren't single quotes supposed to be "hard" quotes in POSIX shells?
Why does dash seem to process escapes inside them, unlike Bash?

```
$ bash --posix -c "echo ['[\\n]']"
[[\n]]
$ dash -c "echo ['[\\n]']"
[[
]]
```

Comment: You need `bash --posix -O xpg_echo -c "echo '[\\n]'"` for the `echo` builtin of `bash` to be fully POSIX compliant. On some systems `xpg_echo` is enabled by default (at least for builds of bash intended for /bin/sh). See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The single quotes do behave identically, it's the `echo` implementation that's different.

When you run `sh -c "echo ['[\\n]']"` (for any `sh`), the first thing that happens is that your interactive shell processes the double-quoted string, turning the `\\` into a single `\`. The string that gets passed to the shell for execution is then `echo ['[\n]']`.

The `echo` command (probably builtin) launched within that inner shell sees the single argument `[[\n]]`, and some implementations of `echo` process C-style backslash-escapes like `\n` for newline, while some others don't.

Try `sh -c "printf '%s\\n' ['[\\n]']"` instead, and see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Comment: Fascinating/horrifying... thanks!